# Jquery : Post Request is breaking while uploading multiple images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csrf, plupload

I am using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) js plugin to upload multiple images in one request. This plugin is working like if someone adding 5 images at a time then post request will go 5 times to upload each of images separately. As we know Post request require unique csrf token but in my case due to same token after one time, post request is failing.

Here is my code ...

```
<c:set var="csrfTokenVal"><csrf:token-value uri="<%=request.getRequestURI()%>"/></c:set>

<script>
var csrftokenV="${csrfTokenVal}";

$("#uploader").plupload({

    // General settings
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    url:'/view/SurgeryNotesComponentController?uploadSurgeryImage=true&'+csrftokenN+'='+csrftokenV,

    // User can upload no more then 20 files in one go (sets multiple_queues to false)
    max_file_count: 10,

    chunk_size: '1mb',

    // Resize images on clientside if we can
    resize : {
        width : 600, 
        height : 610, 
        quality : 90,
        //crop: true // crop to exact dimensions
    },

    filters : {
        // Maximum file size
        max_file_size : '1mb',
        // Specify what files to browse for
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
        ]
    },

    // Rename files by clicking on their titles
    rename: true,

    // Sort files
    sortable: true,

    // Enable ability to drag'n'drop files onto the widget (currently only HTML5 supports that)
    dragdrop: true,

    // Views to activate
    views: {
        list: true,
        thumbs: false, // Show thumbs
        active: 'thumbs'
    },
    init: {
        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            $("#uploader_filelist").show();

        },


        FileUploaded: function(up, file, info, res) {
            var imageObjectArray=$.parseJSON(info.response);
            for(i=0;i<imageObjectArray.objectList.length; i++){
                $('#showfilelist ul').append("<li><a class='delIcon-image' href='#delete' id='delSurgeryImageIcon'></a><a id=" + imageObjectArray.objectList[i].uid + " class='cboxElement imguid' href='${contextPath}/view/SurgeryNotesComponentController?surgeryImage=true&"+csrftokenN+ "="+ csrftokenV+"&attachmentLocation="+imageObjectArray.objectList[i].attachmentLocation+"' target='_blank'><img src='${contextPath}/view/SurgeryNotesComponentController?surgeryImage=true&"+csrftokenN+ "="+ csrftokenV+"&attachmentLocation="+imageObjectArray.objectList[i].attachmentLocation+"'  border='0'>"+"</a> <strong>"+noteAddedMsg+"</strong><span class='image-created'>"+imageObjectArray.objectList[i].formattedDate+" "+byMsg+" "+imageObjectArray.objectList[i].userName+" </span></li>");
            }

            $("#uploader_filelist").empty().hide();
            _SPINE.colorboxOverlay.coloboxPopup();
            _SPINE.surgeryNotes.deleteImages();

            $(".plupload_done .plupload_file_thumb").removeClass("hide")
        },
        ChunkUploaded: function (up, file, response) {
            response = $.parseJSON(response.response || "null");
            if (response.chunk == 3) {
                up.stop();
                up.start();
            }
            console.log(file.loaded);

        }

    },
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : '${siteAssetsUrl}/assets/spine/js/external/Moxie.swf',

    // Silverlight settings../assets/js
    silverlight_xap_url : '${siteAssetsUrl}/assets/spine/js/external/Moxie.xap'
});
</script>
```

Here you can see I am generating scrf token (csrftokenV) and sending it in url to make it post supported.

Now the problem is if I am uploading more than 1 images (lets say 3), then 3 time post request will go. Each time i will get same csrf token and after uploaing first image, furthure images will not work and i will get this exception ....

```
WARNING: potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:127.0.0.1, uri:/**/image, error:request token does not match session token)
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally One of my friend had solved the issue. It can't be possible to handle this issue through client side script so we leverage the power of Java. We had updated the csrfToken based on new request and sent it out with response.

Here is a solution ..

```
        private String updateToken(HttpServletRequest request)
        {
            final HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            CsrfGuard csrfGuard = CsrfGuard.getInstance();
            csrfGuard.updateTokens(request);
            String newToken=(String) session.getAttribute(REQUEST_TOKEN);
            return newToken;
        }
```

Setting newToken in response ...

```
             response.setResult(this.updateToken(request));
             return response;
```

Now we can change the url in beforeUpload event and set new token in the url.

```
 BeforeUpload: function(up, file) 
            {

                up.settings.url='/view/SurgeryNotesComponentController?uploadSurgeryImage=true&'+csrftokenN+'='+tokenRefresh

            }

 FileUploaded: function(up, file, info, res) 
            {
               var imageObjectArray=$.parseJSON(info.response);
                tokenRefresh=imageObjectArray.result;
           }
```